# Declaring a class var. Global

Tags: python, class

So in my code, I tried to declare a var global, but when i reference the var outside of the class, it appears to still be global. I cant find a way for the color variable to become global, ive tried using self.color, but i dont know if i am not implementing it right, or if it doesnt work in my case.

```py
import time

#values
red = (255,0,0) ##actual color value###

r=0 ###current value of color###
green = (0,255,0)

g=0
blue = (0,0,255)

b=0


class RGB():
    def __init__(self):
        global color
    def inc(self,color):
        r = 0
        g = 0
        b = 0
        self.color = color
        if color == r:
            print('---------------------')
        r = self.color
        print('increased')
        print(color)
        time.sleep(1)
        while r < 255:
            color += 1
            print(color)
            r = color
            time.sleep(0.005)
        print()



rgb = RGB()
rgb.inc(r)
print(r)
```

Comment: "global" only affects the function or method in which it is declared.

Comment: If you have an instance variable, and your instance is already global, you shouldn't make its variables global as well

Comment: @oneCricketeer well if it's global, then should I be able to reference it in the last piece of code?

Comment: You're not making `r` global, you're defining a brand new variable called `color`, which are compared by value, not by name

Comment: By any chance are you trying to define a class variable instead of instance variable? in case you are trying to define a class variable which would be same for all instances, then you can define it anywhere inside the class and outside of any function or constructor

Answer (score 0):

`rgb` is already globally defined, making `rgb.color` the global variable you'd use outside the class, not `color` on its own (which is its own variable, and you seem to think `r == color` is checking if the references of these objects (the names of the variables) are equivalent, but this only compares their values)

Within your inc function, you're assigning an instance variable, but only modifying the input parameter, which effectively does nothing in terms of having global or updating the instance variable

This is how you should define an RGB class

```
class RGB():
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b
```

If you want to increment specific values, you would need to define three separate functions rather than compare one input to only one field (unless you did only want to increment red)

For example

```
def inc_red(self, value):
    self.r += value
```